# How can D3 deal with the crs property in a GeoJSON file?

Tags: d3.js

I have been handed over a GeoJSON file where features are using the EPSG:2169 coordinate reference system. It looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "cantons",
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:2169" }},
    "features": […]
}
```

Only when I try to display it using D3.js, I only get a black rectangle. The code is pretty standard:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 960;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(50)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("cantons.json", function(cantons) {
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(cantons.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
});
```

I can see the paths are correctly created but obviously the coordinates are unrealistic. I was thinking the problem might come from this exotic crs, that's why I tried to convert it using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" cantons_new.json cantons.json
```

which gives me:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": […]
}
```

But it does not seem to work either. I'm pretty sure this is nothing, but as I started using D3.js and GDAL last week-end, I'm stuck for the moment. Any help to let me figure out what is happening and how I can deal with this `crs` parameter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing a piece of the puzzle, topojson...

Typically when I have fed d3 geojson data, I utilize the library topojson as well...

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson

ex:

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers();

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

svg.selectAll(".zip_code")
.data(topojson.feature(zip_codes, zip_codes.objects.zip_codes).features)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", function(d) { return "zipcode" + d.id; })
.attr("d", path);
```

.json file looks like:

```
{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale: 
[0.00018809317288465377,0.00017734543345821494],"translate": 
[-85.3864733089842,32.844638824851614]},"objects":{"zip_codes": 
{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
[11]],"id":"30534"}
...
```

This was the d3/map tutorial I started out with:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I literally wrote the code out of Mike's article and was particularly interested in: "If your shapefile uses a gridded coordinate system (e.g., UTM), use -t_srs EPSG:4326 to convert back to conventional latitude and longitude." I will give topojson a try, though if I read it correctly this is just a more efficient version of geojson, am I correct?